# How Innodb Concurrency Tickets working in sorting by mysql?

Tags: mysql, sorting, innodb, analysis

Innodb concurrency tickets how reduced when the sorting performing query running? is tickets applied for sorting or not? If applied how it was calculated by mysql and is there any performance issue occurred when the sorting query scanned lacks of rows?

The working of Innodb concurrency tickets for sorting queries. Performance issue occurred on sorting queries when it takes sort query.

Comment: Sorting is done outside the storage engine, so I don't think innodb concurrency tickets is relevant. Why do you think it is affecting sorting?

Comment: we are experiencing slow queries while the sorting performing queries are running. we are using default concurrency tickets. if the sorting queries return lesser than  the value of concurrency tickets no slow queries occurred. whats your concern about this?

Comment: It's possible that sorting a large result set will also be slow, but it has nothing to do with InnoDB. Sorting large result sets may exceed the `sort_buffer_size` and need to save partially-sorted subsets to disk, then merge them. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html InnoDB uses concurrency ticket for row reads, so a larger result set will use more concurrency tickets. But InnoDB doesn't perform sorting. That is done by the SQL layer in MySQL, outside the storage engine. This should have nothing to do with InnoDB concurrency tickets.